# Google, Facebook oauth Login for SPA without Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, single-page-application

I am working on a Single page radio player web application. I want to integrate Facebook or Google Oauth login in my app.

I want the radio player to continue playing while user login into the app using Oauth login flow. How to implement Oauth Login without Page Refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript SDK for this, with the FB.login function: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

If the docs are not enough for you, here´s a tutorial: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/